# Cannot push local changes on remote repository in visual studio?

Tags: github

Changes made in the visual studio are not committed successfully into a remote repository on GitHub.

Comment: Any error you are getting? How are you trying to do this? Did you try pushing the changes to remote?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am not getting any error while committing the code. Actually, i am making some changes in class but when I  save this changes visual studio doesn't show me in new changes. That's why I am not able to push my current changes to the remote repository.

Comment: Can you share what is being displayed by the visual studio? I am sure you are aware that changes can be pushed only after committing them.

Comment: while I making changes in any file then the visual studio is showing me the changes but when I save that changes then the visual studio is automatically undoing the changes.I am not getting where these changes are saved.